Yotpo initWidgets() is not a function in Vue component
I am trying to call the initWidgets(); method provided by Yotpo to re-initialize our reviews widget on page load, per their recommendations. However, I keep getting the error window.yotpoWidgetsContainer.initWidgets is not a function
I have the widget instance in a child component, and emit an event to the parent when I know that window.yotpoWidgetsContainer exists:
mounted() {
    if (window.yotpoWidgetsContainer) {
        this.$emit('widgetsContainerLoaded');
    }
},

(also console logging window.yotpoWidgetsContainer there confirms that it exists and has the initWidgets() function available.
I handle this event @widgetsContainerLoaded="initializeYotpoWidget(0)" in the parent with the following method:
initializeYotpoWidget(count) {
            let i = count
            try {
                window.yotpoWidgetsContainer.initWidgets();
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
                if (attempt >= 5) {
                    return;
                }
                this.initializeYotpoWidget(i++);
            }
        },

But on each attempt, I get the error that initWidgets is not a function -- I'm not sure what's going on. Any insight would be much appreciated!!

"also console logging window.yotpoWidgetsContainer there confirms that it exists and has the initWidgets() function available" - how exactly? The problem is potentially in the method of debugging. Console should be used as the last resort, and it's often misused. It's unknown when and on which condition yotpoWidgetsContainer is created and whether it's possible for initWidgets to be conditionally available. The error means that yotpoWidgetsContainer is not undefined but initWidgets is anything but a function, including undefined. Create a debugger breakpoint and check what exactly it is.

Regarding console log, information about an object is lazily retrieved. This means that the log message shows the content of an object at the time when it's first viewed, not when it was logged. It could very well be that the exact moment you console log that the function is not in fact available, but is a short time later (which your browser console will update to show as soon as it can).  To be absolutely sure, you should stringify the object, e.g. console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(window.yotpoWidgetsContainer)))

Thanks this was super helpful! I threw a breakpoint into my component, and was able to figure it out from there -- turns out I just needed to call this stuff from the updated hook, which I hadn't been using.
